# Hybris cron job trigger doesn't work

Tags: triggers, cron, sap-commerce-cloud

I am writing a trigger for cron job from backoffice or with impex according to examples. But cron job is not executed though the next activation time has elapsed. How can I activate triggers.

There is an issue in sap page but I couldn't log in.

https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/preview/en/2556122

Comment: How did you configure the trigger? Is your cron job activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one site where you can get information. There is the documentation for hybris versions < 6 available at https://wiki.hybris.com/. Here is the part for creating a trigger for cronjobs:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/cronjob+-+Technical+Guide#cronjob-TechnicalGuide-CreatingaTriggerthroughtheBackoffice

For version 6 there is a newer documentation available at https://help.hybris.com/

Answer (score 7):

When developing code, for performance issue cron jobs load cancelled in local.properties by pproperty. When removing this line, jobs triggered.

cronjob.timertask.loadonstartup=false

Answer (score 1):

You need S-User for getting detail. Partners and customers can get S-User. Try to register at launchpad.sap.com with your business email for getting your S-User, your admin will be informed about your registration.

Document hasn't got detail, it is only contains groovy script for checking your cronjob configuration.

You can try to adding trigger in backoffice to cronjob for correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Check Task engine is in running condition or not on the node in which cronjob need to be executed. If not then you can run task engine by following groovy script.

```
engine = taskService.getEngine();
running = engine.isRunning();
println "Before:"+running
engine.start();
running = engine.isRunning();
println "After:"+running
```

Trigger should work after task engine starts runnning. You can run this groovy through hac.

Comment: How to check if the task engine on the respective node is running?

Comment: Use this groovy code in rollback mode.
engine = taskService.getEngine();
running = engine.isRunning();
println "Before:"+running
These are the first three lines given in above answer.